# Implementing a semaphore with multiple producers (with goroutines)

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

This has been the bane of my existence.

```
type ec2Params struct {
    sess *session.Session
    region string
}

type cloudwatchParams struct {
    cl cloudwatch.CloudWatch
    id string
    metric string
    region string
}

type request struct {
    ec2Params
    cloudwatchParams
}

// Control concurrency and sync
var maxRoutines = 128
var sem chan bool
var req chan request

func main() {
    sem := make(chan bool, maxRoutines)
    for i := 0; i < maxRoutines; i++ {
        sem <- true
    }
    req := make(chan request)
    go func() { // This is my the producer
        for _, arn := range arns {
            arnCreds := startSession(arn)
            for _, region := range regions {
                sess, err := session.NewSession(
                    &aws.Config{****})
                if err != nil {
                    failOnError(err, "Can't assume role")
                }
                req <- request{ec2Params: ec2Params{ **** }}
            }
        }
    }() 
    for f := range(req) {
        <- sem
        if (ec2Params{}) != f.ec2Params {
            go getEC2Metrics(****)
        } else {
            // I should be excercising this line of code too, 
            // but I'm not :(
            go getMetricFromCloudwatch(****) 
        }   
        sem <- true
    }
}
```

`getEC2Metrics` and `getCloudwatchMetrics` are the goroutines to execute

```
func getMetricFromCloudwatch(cl cloudwatch.CloudWatch, id, metric, region string) {
    // Magic
}

func getEC2Metrics(sess *session.Session, region string) {
    ec := ec2.New(sess)
    var ids []string
    l, err := ec.DescribeInstances(&ec2.DescribeInstancesInput{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        for _, rsv := range l.Reservations {
            for _, inst := range rsv.Instances {
                ids = append(ids, *inst.InstanceId)
            }
        }
        metrics := cfg.AWSMetric.Metric
        if len(ids) >= 0 {
            cl := cloudwatch.New(sess)
            for _, id := range ids{
                for _, metric := range metrics {
                    // For what I can tell, execution get stuck here
                    req <- request{ cloudwatchParams: ***** }}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both the anonymous producer in `main` and `getEC2Metrics` should publish data to `req` asynchronically, but so far it seems like whatever `getEC2Metrics` is publishing to the channel is never processed.
It looks like there is something stopping me from publishing from within a goroutine, but I haven't found anything. I would love to know how to go about this and to produce the indended behavior (This is, an actually working semaphore).

The base of the implementation can be found here: https://burke.libbey.me/conserving-file-descriptors-in-go/

Comment: You're not using your semaphore, you simply take out a token dispatch a goroutine and put the token back -- you never block. (BTW, you don't have to "fill" the semaphore, you can reverse it and send a token to take the semaphore, and receive a token to release it)

Comment: You are completely RIGHT!!! I've updated that and found the other issue, which is that I need to pass a channel reference to my getEC2Metrics function; I cannot use the global definition for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Im frantic, JimB's comment made the wheel spin and now I've solved this!

```
// Control concurrency and sync
var maxRoutines = 128
var sem chan bool
var req chan request // Not reachable inside getEC2Metrics

func getEC2Metrics(sess *session.Session, region string, req chan <- request ) {
    ....
    ....
            for _, id := range ids{
                for _, metric := range metrics {
                    req <- request{ **** }} // When using the global req, 
                                            // this would block
                }
            }
    ....
    ....
}

func main() {
    sem := make(chan bool, maxRoutines)
    for i := 0; i < maxRoutines; i++ {
        sem <- true    
    }
    req := make(chan request)
    go func() {
        // Producing tasks
    }()
    for f := range(req) {
        <- sem // checking out tickets outside the goroutine does block 
               //outside of the goroutine
        go func() {
            defer func() { sem <- true }()
            if (ec2Params{}) != f.ec2Params {
                getEC2Metrics(****, req) // somehow sending the channel makes
                                         // possible to publish to it
            } else {
                getMetricFromCloudwatch(****)
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

There were two issues:

1. The semaphore was not locking (I think it is because I was checking out and in tokens inside a goroutine, so there was a race condition probably).
2. For some reason, The global channel req was not being addressed properly by `getEC2Metrics`, so it would leave alll the goroutines stuck while trying to publish to a channel that was apparently on scope, but it wasn't (I really don't know why yet).

I've honestly just had luck with the second item, so far I haven't found any docs regarding this quirk, but at the end I'm glad it's working.

Comment: There's no "race condition" on sending and receiving from a channel, they are a synchronization primitive made for concurrent use.  You're shadowing the global `req` channel in main.